# Error in SFDX CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

getting below error,
force:project:create -n projectname
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

when running command - force:project:create -n projectname in CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to wrap the projectname in quotes like

```
sfdx force:project:create -n "your project name"
```

Hope that helps.